# How can i do parameterization for multiple json files or payload in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-3.2

How can i do parameterization for multiple json files or payload in jmeter.

I am trying to to parameterization for json payload in jmeter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parameterize POST body in JMeter HTTP POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45856518/parameterize-post-body-in-jmeter-http-post)

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) inside the JSON file(s) and want JMeter to evaluate the variables "on the fly" - make sure to wrap calls to them into [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) like:

```
${__eval(${__FileToString(/path/to/file.json,,)})}
```

[image]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)